# ASP.NET MVC controller get Request.Form in string format how to get value from there in my class object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, class

I have this class:

```
Test t = new Test();
```

The class looks like this:

```
public partial class Test
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string ThirdName { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, I am getting:

```
string emp = Request.Form["mydata"];
```

`emp` value is like this:

```
[ { "FirstName":"john", "SecondName":"carry", "ThirdName":"miller" } ]
```

How can I get these values from `emp` and set in `Test` object in order to save it?

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)   
{  
     stringjsonData = @ "{'FirstName': 'john', 'SecondName':'carry','ThirdName':'miller'}";
     var myTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Test> (stringjsonData);  
     Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Hi ", myTest.FirstName, " " + myTest.SecondName, " " + myTest.ThirdName));  
     Console.ReadLine();  
}  

  public class Test  
   {  
     public string FirstName {  
      get;  
      set;  
   }  
     public string SecondName {  
      get;  
      set;  
   }  
     public string ThirdName {  
      get;  
      set;  
   }
 }
```